# Did VS 2015 VB compiler lose the ability of incremental building?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, compilation, visual-studio-2015

I have 500KLOC [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) project containing about 1000 code files.
[visual-studio-2012](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012) was able to compile the solution in **25** seconds, while [visual-studio-2015](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015) needs **150** seconds and computer goes unresponsive several times during the process. This is worse than time of *complete rebuild* in VS 2012.

Based on the performance, it looks that VS 2015 compiler always does *complete rebuild* instead of compilation of changed modules only (before linking phase). **Is there some option to switch this *complete rebuild* behavior back to fast *incremental building*?**

Microsoft claims that in VS 2015 they introduced completely rewritten compiler, with overall speed improved up to 50%. What am I missing?

Comment: .Net projects do not have modules or a linking phase.  What is your project structure?

Comment: @SLaks – number of class files in directory tree about 4 levels deep. They also include maybe 300 WinForms forms.  No extraordinary VS solution/project features involved.

Comment: The Roslyn integration did not go well, thousands of bugs.  But they did do a good job on background compilation, complaints about "goes unresponsive several times" are not common.  You'll need to get the machine healthy again, maybe you need more RAM, maybe the disk is too fragmented, maybe anti-malware is entirely too aggressive, something like that.

Comment: @HansPassant – Thank you for enlightened comment – see the answer. BTW I still have VS 2012 + VS 2015 side-by-side. I can see 20-25 secs vs. 150+ secs even today. i7 CPU and SSD drives only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Anti-malware protection on my machine was too aggressive.

It looks that there was change between VS 2012 and VS 2015 compiler in how installed anti-malware (from ESET) perceives the result being built by the compiler.

After disabling the anti-malware protection for project directory, compilation time dropped from **170** seconds to **58** seconds. Not faster than VS 2012 compiler, but much more bearable.

The credit for the idea goes to [Hans Passant's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657284/did-vs-2015-vb-compiler-lose-the-ability-of-incremental-building/35657911#comment58995343_35657284).